# Do something with thumbnail image on post publish

Tags: plugins, custom-field, metabox, post-thumbnails, publish

For example get width and height of the image and save it to a custom field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually Wordpress offer a good hook  , You can get data from Post  Published , for more you can follow this example : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post
Example of a simple  update of custom field:

```
/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

// First we need to check if the current user is authorised to do this action. 
if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
    return;
} 
else {
if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
    return;
 }

$mydata = 'something'; // Do something with $mydata 

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $mydata );
}
```

Comment: welp didnt know it was this easy..But where should i put the code at? Functions.php?

Comment: @MeghGandhi Yes you have to add it at your function.php  . But you must know a bit of php for that .

Comment: Here is a simple example to update e custom field on post save .

Comment: i have seen it somewhere

Comment: Yeap is a good point  to start

Comment: i didnt get you @h-techpc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47913/discussion-between-megh-gandhi-and-h-techpc).